# Configuring networking with QEMU for OpenBSD 6.7 guest on Debian Buster host

Tags: debian, networking, virtual-machine, qemu, openbsd

I have a host machine running Debian 10 and am using QEMU to run an OpenBSD 6.7 guest (amd64). My current invocation of QEMU is as follows:

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -m 512 -drive if=virtio,file=my_image.qcow2 -enable-kvm -netdev user,id=mynet0,hostfwd=tcp:127.0.0.1:7922-:22 -device virtio-net,netdev=mynet0
```

On the guest machine, I can access remote Subversion servers and also the OpenBSD package repositories just fine, but whenever I try to ping a remote host, it just hangs indefinitely until I kill it:

```
$ ping google.com
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

Furthermore, I have an assignment that involves the usual C socket programming (on the guest machine). Whenever I make a call to `connect`, I get `Network is unreachable` back.

Here are my interfaces configured on the **guest machine**:

```
$ ifconfig
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 32768
    index 3 priority 0 llprio 3
    groups: lo
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x3
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
vio0: flags=808843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST,AUTOCONF4> mtu 1500
    lladdr 52:54:00:12:34:56
    index 1 priority 0 llprio 3
    groups: egress
    media: Ethernet autoselect
    status: active
    inet 10.0.2.15 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.0.2.255
enc0: flags=0<>
    index 2 priority 0 llprio 3
    groups: enc
    status: active
pflog0: flags=141<UP,RUNNING,PROMISC> mtu 33136
    index 4 priority 0 llprio 3
    groups: pflog
```

and my routes (also on the **guest machine**):

```
$ route show
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags   Refs      Use   Mtu  Prio Iface
default            10.0.2.2           UGS        5        9     -     8 vio0 
base-address.mcast localhost          URS        0        0 32768     8 lo0  
10.0.2/24          10.0.2.15          UCn        2        0     -     4 vio0 
10.0.2.2           52:55:0a:00:02:02  UHLch      3        5     -     3 vio0 
10.0.2.3           52:55:0a:00:02:03  UHLc       0        8     -     3 vio0 
10.0.2.15          52:54:00:12:34:56  UHLl       0        8     -     1 vio0 
10.0.2.255         10.0.2.15          UHb        0        0     -     1 vio0 
127/8              localhost          UGRS       0        0 32768     8 lo0  
localhost          localhost          UHhl       1        2 32768     1 lo0  

Internet6:
Destination        Gateway            Flags   Refs      Use   Mtu  Prio Iface
::/96              localhost          UGRS       0        0 32768     8 lo0  
localhost          localhost          UHhl      10       20 32768     1 lo0  
::ffff:0.0.0.0/96  localhost          UGRS       0        0 32768     8 lo0  
2002::/24          localhost          UGRS       0        0 32768     8 lo0  
2002:7f00::/24     localhost          UGRS       0        0 32768     8 lo0  
2002:e000::/20     localhost          UGRS       0        0 32768     8 lo0  
2002:ff00::/24     localhost          UGRS       0        0 32768     8 lo0  
fe80::/10          localhost          UGRS       0        0 32768     8 lo0  
fec0::/10          localhost          UGRS       0        0 32768     8 lo0  
fe80::1%lo0        fe80::1%lo0        UHl        0        0 32768     1 lo0  
ff01::/16          localhost          UGRS       1        1 32768     8 lo0  
ff01::%lo0/32      fe80::1%lo0        Um         0        1 32768     4 lo0  
ff02::/16          localhost          UGRS       1        1 32768     8 lo0  
ff02::%lo0/32      fe80::1%lo0        Um         0        1 32768     4 lo0
```

This leads me to believe that my QEMU setup is somehow misconfigured.

**How can I fix the network configuration to allow the guest machine to talk (properly) to the outside world?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `-netdev user` works fine with TCP and UDP but not ICMP. Try running `tcpdump` on the host machine's interface(s) to see if the ICMP packets are being properly forwarded and/or translated.

I'm not sure on how `-netdev user` works on the host machine, but if you want your guest machine to behave more like a proper member of your network perhaps creating a `tap` interface on the host machine, bridging it with the host's physical interface (both require `root` access), and then using `-netdev tap` would be a better alternative.